# Java multiple threads eating up all the CPU Resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some a java code that reads an email inbox.

Once this service is turned on, it spawns a parent thread that keeps checking if a new mail has arrived every 5 seconds. It checks and if no mail has arrived, it sleeps for 5 seconds. If a new mail has arrived, depending on mail burst, it spawns up to max 10 worker threads to parse those emails. and once all the mails are parsed, and no new mail has arrived, the worker threads are killed after 5 seconds of inactivity. The parent thread keeps on pinging ALWAYS.

There are 7-8 such services, reading different inboxes, that keep on running on my aws machine, which has a 4 core CPU. These services are eating upto 350% of my cpu usage which I can see via "top" command.

I want to know if there is a way I can limit these threads from eating CPU resource all the time. This is slowing down all other processes, because they do not get CPU usage because of contention.

This is the code in parent thread

```
 @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!this.isThreadKillRequested()) {
                    if (this.getMessageCount() > 0) {
                        WorkerThread worker = getWorkerThread();
                        if (worker != null && !worker.isAlive()) {
                            worker.start();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(this.isAllThreadIdle()){
                            //ModelUtil.printOutput("all idle. nothing to do");
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_SLEEP_TIME);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                ErrorLogger.logError("InterruptedException exception in monitoring thread",
                        GlobalConfig.msgException + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    private WorkerThread getWorkerThread() {
            WorkerThread worker = null;
            for (Map.Entry<String, ThreadPerformance> entry : this.threadPool.entrySet()) {
                ThreadPerformance p = entry.getValue();
                if (p.isThreadIdle()) {
                    worker = p.getThisThread();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (worker == null && this.threadPool.size() < MAX_POOL_SIZE) {
                double overallThroughput = 0.00;
                //some logic to calculate throughput
                if (overallThroughput < MIN_THROUGHPUT) {
                    worker = new WorkerThread(this, this.getUniqueThreadId());
                    //add in pool
                }
                System.out.println("Overall Throughput - " + overallThroughput);
                System.out.println("Pool Size - " + this.threadPool.size());
            }
            return worker;
        }
```

Comment: No mystery. 1. Check less often. 2. Spawn fewer threads.

Comment: 3. Don't spawn new workers while old workers are still running, i.e. use an `ExecutorService` with a limited thread pool.

Comment: Like it wasn't obvious to me. I have performance constraints to achieve. I would appreciate any other suggestions though.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal You keep arguing with people's suggestions but you haven't actually done any profiling to find out ***what part of your code is eating the CPU cycles***.  If you don't know where the bottleneck is you cannot optimize effectively.  Please do some profiling and come back when you have identified the cause of the CPU usage.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for my comments. Can you please suggest some profiling tool I can use which will be useful here. I dont know about them. I am using a linux machine.

Comment: @EJP How is ExecuterService better than threads? I have my own code that limits the number of threads spawned. I am asking for some more information here. or any link that can help me.

Comment: It's better because it is already written and already works. You don't know that about your own code. Regarding your prior comment, cut it out. I have *already* made three suggestions. You can't use the entire processor to achieve your performance requirements, and the idea is to *tune* the parameters I mentioned until you *just* achieve them. If you can't achieve them without 350% CPU usage, or whatever is deemed too much, your performance requirement is infeasible. This also is no mystery.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal what is "email inbox"? Is it local or remote?

Comment: @EJP: I think I forgot to mention, the worker threads are alive for a short period of time. They are killed after 5 sec of inactivity. Only 1 parent thread per inbox is alive all the time that keeps pinging every 5 sec. If I have 8 parent threads for 8 inboxes, they alone eat up 350% of CPU. Doesn't it seem like too much of resource consumption for just 8 threads. I will anyways try the code with ExecutorService.

Comment: @EJP: This program is supposed to be a background task. If I ping less often, users may notice delays in processing once they send an email.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Any suggestions please, on what profiling tool would suit for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the threads CPU consumption is easiest by slowing down the refresh cycle and condensing threads. Try every 20 seconds and limiting the number of worker threads to 4. Unless there's a need for all of the threads and a fast refresh rate, it's unnecessary pressure on the CPU. Especially when 8 mailboxes are being checked.

The probability of all mailboxes receiving a large amount of new mail, at the same time, is low. Thus, a total thread count can be kept and the number of threads per mailbox can be distributed based on the percentage of new items per mailbox. This will increase the throughput for the mailbox that needs it the most while limiting the number of threads to a manageable amount.

Comment: I have to have a minimum throughput while parsing emails. If there is a huge burst of mails, code automatically spawns new threads upto max of 10 threads.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal Does each thread handle a new email? Or does it parse different aspects of the email? Or something else?

Comment: each set of worker thread parses same inbox for mails, so that I can increase throughput (number of mails parsed per second), there is 1 parent thread and a set of worker threads per inbox. All worker threads do the same thing. parent thread just monitors and spawns or kills worker threads.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal I'll add more to the original answer as a possible solution for this issue.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal You don't 'parse' an inbox. You parse an *email*. You should have *one* threading downloading emails and *then* as many worker-parser threads as you need to achieve the required performance *and no more.* The network isn't multi-threaded,, and it doesn't have multiple CPUs.

Comment: @sellc: the probability of sudden burst is low. That is why most of the time it is just a monitoring parent thread that is alive. All other worker threads are killed after 5 seconds of inactivity. Those monitoring threads themselves are eating 350% CPU.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal The solution I mentioned would only have one main monitoring thread.